# whether configured files lost while VM instance stopping

Tags: virtual-machines, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am using a google cloud VM instance for my client to configure a web site. Client will not use the site for the next 6 months. For reducing the bill If I stop the VM instance for a period is it affect the configured application in VM instance means the files will lost or not? Also If I start the VM instance again can I get the configured details?

Comment: Why don't you just try it with a scratch instance and find out?

Comment: OK. i will try....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you configure a web server all your web configuration is stored in a Standard persistent disk or SSD persistent disk,the disk is attached to your VM instance it will not be impacted by stooping or restarting the VM instance.
Unless if you delete your instance and you didn't [enable deletion Protection](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preventing-accidental-vm-deletion#setting_deletion_protection_during_instance_creation).

If you start your VM instance after stopping it for 6 month you will find your configuration details stored.

you can backup your data with [snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots) since there are only charged for the total size of the snapshot $0.026/GB per month plus the Network charges for snapshot restoration.